# iOS Slack app - Threads stuck bold / unread

Tags: slack, ios

I have followed Slack's instructions to clear unread messages and still "Threads" is bold in my Slack app. It is not bold on my desktop app.

[Slack's instructions](https://slack.com/help/articles/360001559367-Troubleshoot-Slack-notifications#mac-5):

> **Mark everything as read on desktop**
>
> - From the Slack desktop app, open the affected workspace.
> - Press Shift + Esc.
>
> **Clear the Slack app cache**
>
> - Tap "You" at the bottom of your screen.
> - Tap Preferences.
> - Tap Advanced.
> - Tap Reset Cache.
>
> **Clear app data from your device settings** In addition to clearing the Slack app cache, you can also clear the app data from your device.
>
> - Open Settings on your device.
> - Scroll down to Slack in the list of apps.
> - Tap the toggle next to Reset Cache on Next Launch.
> - Open the app to reset the cache.
>   Note: This will log you out of all workspaces you're signed in to.

This third step did NOT log me out of my workspaces FWIW.

Comment: Try quitting and reopening the app after the 3rd step